# Can I redirect users seamlessly from a personal Facebook page to a business Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

A coworker set up a personal Facebook page in error; It should be a business Facebook page.

There are several friends on the personal page that need to be redirected to the correct Facebook business page.

Can I seamlessly redirect users from the incorrect personal page to the correct business page?

Answer (score 9):

Better off, just migrate your page https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?migrate

All your friends will be converted to fans, Your pics should be kept also.

Hope it helps!! :)

PS: If you want to redirect users from one fanpage to another you've to do the following:

1. Join facebook developers: developers.facebook.com
2. Create an app an choose page tab. Configure your app accordingly http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/
3. In your code, just add:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = YOUR_OTHER_PAGE_URL</script>
   ```

I use this with facebook apps, but it should work!

Answer (score -1):

Or just use the app static html like in this vid:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cs1DNc5O3M